# python manage.py syncdb import error

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am trying to learn django and setting up an mysql data base
in the settings.py i have made these changes

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'name',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '****password****',
    }
}
```

I am usin django 1.9. how to use my mysql database as the following error is coming.

```
(project) C:\Users\soumyadeep dasgupta\Desktop\Project\src>python manage.py runs
erver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management

(project) C:\Users\soumyadeep dasgupta\Desktop\Project\src>pip install MySQL-pyt
hon
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): MySQL-python in c:\use
rs\soumya~1\envs\project\lib\site-packages\mysql_python-1.2.3-py2.7-win32.egg

(project) C:\Users\soumyadeep dasgupta\Desktop\Project\src>python manage.py sync
db
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

installing djano again in the virtual env resolved this giving me this error

```
(project) C:\Users\soumyadeep dasgupta\Desktop\Project\src>python manage.py sync
db
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\SOUMYA~1\Envs\project\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\
__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\SOUMYA~1\Envs\project\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\
__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\SOUMYA~1\Envs\project\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", li
ne 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\SOUMYA~1\Envs\project\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py
", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\Users\SOUMYA~1\Envs\project\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py",
 line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\SOUMYA~1\Envs\project\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mod
els.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\SOUMYA~1\Envs\project\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\bas
e_user.py", line 49, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\SOUMYA~1\Envs\project\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.p
y", line 108, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\SOUMYA~1\Envs\project\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.p
y", line 307, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\SOUMYA~1\Envs\project\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\option
s.py", line 263, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length(
))
  File "C:\Users\SOUMYA~1\Envs\project\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py",
 line 36, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\SOUMYA~1\Envs\project\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", li
ne 212, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\SOUMYA~1\Envs\project\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", li
ne 116, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\SOUMYA~1\Envs\project\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysq
l\base.py", line 28, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: DLL l
oad failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Comment: One reason people commonly get that error is because Django isn't installed in their virtual environment. I see from your command line that you're in a virtual environment called "project". 

It's possible that you installed Django on your system but not in the virtual environment. 

Try running "pip install django" again, with your virtualenv activated, and see if you still get the rror.

Comment: If that isn't the case, please post the result of running the command "pip freeze" so we can see what you currently have installed

Comment: Note however that `syncdb` was [removed in 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/#features-removed-in-1-9).